# Sequential filling of a jagged array. How does this code work?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I was going through one of the solutions on the jagged array and could not follow a few of the below lines. Can anyone help me in understanding the below-the-line how the `count` is being utilized here. I do understand basics of Java but not getting a vision why count is exactly used here.

Program to demonstrate 2-D jagged array in Java:

```java
int arr[][] = new int[2][];
// Making the above array Jagged
// First row has 3 columns
arr[0] = new int[3];
// Second row has 2 columns
arr[1] = new int[2];
// Initializing array
int count = 0;//why do we need count 
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
        arr[i][j] = count++; //how this line of code will work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add output to this code. The `count` variable is needed to sequentially fill the array with integers from `0` and so on.

```java
int[][] arr = new int[2][];
arr[0] = new int[3];
arr[1] = new int[2];
int count = 0;
// iterate through the rows of the array
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    // iterate through the columns of the array
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
        // set the array element and increment the counter
        arr[i][j] = count++;

// output
for (int[] row : arr) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4]
```